# PostgreSQL Views with geometry on QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgresql, sql, sql-view

Not entirely sure what kind of rules does QGIS need to consume SQL views

So I've had some success in using an id column and a geometry column but now that I'm doing something a bit more complex, it's just not working at all, returning the error that the layer is not valid and cannot be added to the map

Now when I do an export of my view, and then add it to QGIS as a layer using the "add delimited text layer", it just works fine, so this really makes it confusing for me

My query is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW build.project_area
AS WITH hulls(hull, units, id, name) AS (
     SELECT st_concavehull(st_collect(pt.geom), 0.99::double precision) AS hull,
        count(*) AS units,
        pt.id,
        name
       FROM pt
         JOIN table2 USING (id)
      GROUP BY id, name
    )
 SELECT 
hulls.id,
st_geometrytype(hulls.hull) AS hull_type,
    CASE
        WHEN st_geometrytype(hulls.hull) = 'ST_Polygon'::text THEN hulls.hull::geometry(Polygon,27700)
        ELSE st_buffer(hulls.hull, 25::double precision)::geometry(Polygon,27700)
    END AS geom,
hulls.units,
hulls.name
FROM hulls;
```

Basically this query turns points that have the same attribute into a concavehull.

In case points are not a polygon, then it turns the points into a buffer.

How to make this work on QGIS?

EDIT: apparently changing from st_concavehull to st_convexhull makes the whole view work. I'll delete this if there's no input to this soon

Comment: a bit late, but: likely the result contains different geometry types / empty geometrycollections / invalid geometries. QGIS refuses to load such layers.